# Insert button after mysqli check fails

Tags: php, mysqli

So, this is my little line of code - but it simply doesn't work. It gets completly ignored and I don't know why. Can anybody help me?
The button should be displayed if the user_level matches 1 in my db.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'dbuser', 'psw', 'db');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = '1'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) {

} else {

?>
<a href="AdminLayout.php">
<button>Admin</button>

</a>


<?php
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please explain - what SHOULD happen.

Comment: The button should be displayed if the user_level matches 1 in my db.

Comment: So run query directly on mysql, see results. Are you sure that there're records in your table?

Comment: yup, I run a profile.php where I display my db users to check if everything is right. And there it is correctly displayed!

Comment: You store level as a string?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know. It is stored either as a INT or a VARCHAR

Comment: run this query: SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user_level = '1'

Comment: this works, but now it is displayed for every user, even when the user_level is 2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now this way:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {

        $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

       }
    $link = 'VignettenUebersichtlayout.php';
    if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == $r['user_level']) {     
        printf(' <a href="' .$link. '">
                    <button style="background-image:url(\'blabla.jpg\');">                  
                    </button>
                    </a> ');
                    }

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need

```
"SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE `user_level` = '1'"
```

` <---- needed around column

Instead of

```
"SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = '1'"
```

Comment: what do you mean with " ` <---- needed around column "?

Comment: `user_level` instead of plainly user_level

Comment: Well i cannot add ` on stackoverflow as they are converted into markup and code editor is not available on mobile :-(  so replace 0 with ` --- 0user_level0

Comment: They don't need ticks around the column, why would you think that? Had their column been `user-level` with a hyphen I'd agree, but not with the underscore.

Comment: Hmm i have gotten errors due to that several times. It could ofc be related to what you say, ill try it later :-)